# Viberwrapper-indicator stopped working

Tags: 14.04, icons, viber

After like a week of using viberwrapper-indicator it suddenly stopped working, and the floating icon appeared once again, so now I see both icons. I tried reboot, reinstall of both viber and the wrapper, and still nothing works. Any ideas :( ?

Comment: I experienced the same problem. Viber-wrapper indicator is working, but there is still old Viber icon at wrong position.

Comment: I solved the problem (manually). I installed older version. I replace /usr/bin/viberwrapper-indicator with older file (found in my 15.04 installation). I think some older version of this file (DEB installation) can be found and reinstalled in /var/cache/apt/archives

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem appears randomly. Most often there is no indicator appears but the main Viber window appears, some times Viber indicator works normally, some times the original indicator appears in the wrong position and very rarely there are both indicators.
The solution for me is to create AnyName.desktop file in ~/.config/autostart (not in system-wise autorun folder. AnyName is any unique valid name) with the following code:

```
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/viberwrapper-indicator
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=30
Name=Viber Indicator
Comment=Run Viber
```

This cause automatic start of Viber indicator 30 seconds after system login. The last lines "Name" and "Comment" may contain any human-understandable text after "=". The value "30" for "X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay" works for me but can be changed for different computers. In my case absence of this statement cause no initialization of my USB sound card (May be conflict with its driver initialization).